# Exclude object property on JSON output

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a user model with username and password.
I dont want the password to be displayed in the api response, but it is required on signup. So `[JsonIgnore]` wont work.
Any suggestions?

```
public class User {
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't send your domain/entity on API response but create DTO with only the properties you need.

Comment: Are you saying that you are using the same model for two actions — sign up and something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's why you should separate your actual entity and model. You should create a model / viewmodel and send that as response from your API / MVC controller like

```
public class UserModel 
{
  public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Another piece of advice, never include any data validation in your actual entity, rather you should have those validation `[Required]` in your model / viewmodel; and should keep the entity away from this clutter.